# ASP.NET User login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, identity

I have created a simple ASP.Net application with a database consisting of tables such as Classes, Parents, Students, Subjects, and Teachers.

There will be two entities interacting with this application by signing-in which will be the Teachers and Parents.

My question is how do I link the Teachers in my Teachers table instead of saving every new user who registers in the AspNetUsers table which comes with AspNetIdentity.

Once A Teacher/Parent logs in I want to be able to show details relating to that Teacher/Parent. For example when a teacher logs in I want to show all the classes he/she teaches which i retrieve from the database.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC so i appologies if i am asking something very obvious. Any help will be appritiated.

**UPDATE**

Ok so after the suggestion from Chris to inherit from the **ApplicationUser** I managed to update my database and now I have the following structure for my database.

[Entity Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2d5BG.jpg)

Now I am a little confused on where the **Parent** and **Teacher** tables are and how exactly will i be retrieving those entities from the database if they are all in one table **"AspNetUsers"**.

**UPDATE 2**

So i have this piece of code in my AccountController

```
public AccountController()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
        {
        }

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
        }

        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
```

And this is what the Register() method looks like:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var Teacher = new Teacher
                    {
                        UserName = model.UserName,
                        FirstName = model.FirstName,
                        LastName = model.LastName,
                    };

                    // Add the Address properties:
                    user.UserName = model.UserName;
                    user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                    user.LastName = model.LastName;

                    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
                    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
                    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Teacher"));

                    await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Teacher");

                    await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

Refering to Chris comment how do I set up an instance of ApplicationUserManager when a new user registers as a new Teacher?

Comment: There are no dumb questions here. You have asked a very good question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AspNetIdentity you will have to change the storage mechanism a bit to really leverage AspNetIdentity. Simple thing is that all those entities (Teacher/Parent) who require authentication or need to go through login process should be saved in AspNetusers table to leverage the default mechanism of AspNetIdnetity authentication process which generates claims. If you store the user details (who are to be authenticated) in your custom tables instead of AspNetIdentity's default tables then it will have no mechanism to trace that.

> There will be two entities interacting with this application by
>   signing-in which will be the Teachers and Parents.

Teachers and parents will have lot of common properties like firstName,LastName, mobileNumber etc which makes perfect sense to store in AspNetUsers table and get them as claims after the authentication process of AspNetIdentity.

> For example when a teacher logs in I want to show all the classes
>   he/she teaches which i retrieve from the database

For this you will have to have foreign key from `AspNetUser`'s table

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would i add a foreign key to my Subjects table from the AspNetUsers table as I need to assosiate each subject with a User of type Teacher.

Answer (score 0):

One of the whole reasons Identity exists is to enable extensibility with authentication. Otherwise, we could have all just stuck with the old ASP.NET Membership. So, use it. The best way to handle this is via inheritance. Your base "user" will be `ApplicationUser`, and any and all subtypes of "users" should inherit from that:

```
public class Teacher : ApplicationUser

public class Parent : ApplicationUser
```

This will result, by default, in single-table inheritance, where all the properties from all subtypes of `ApplicationUser` will all go into the same table, i.e. `AspNetUsers`, by default. A discriminator column will be added, which will contain the value of the class Entity Framework should instantiate when the record is queried from the database, i.e. `Teacher`, `Parent`, or `ApplicationUser`. For the most part this works great. The only sticky point to be aware of is that since all the properties of subtypes go in one table, you cannot have non-nullable properties on those types. For example, if there were some property on `Teacher` that you wanted to enforce at a database level always had a value, you could not do that because `Parent` or `ApplicationUser` would have no means of providing a value. However, you can always require a value at the UI level, just not on the database.

If that's totally unacceptable, you can use table-per-type inheritance, instead. With that strategy, you would end up with separate tables for `Parent` and `Teacher`, in addition to the `AspNetUsers` table. However, only the properties unique to that type would go on those tables. All the properties on `ApplicationUser` would stay in `AspNetUsers` and a one-to-one would be added between `AspNetUsers` and `Teacher` and `Parent`, respectively. This means that in order to retrieve a `Teacher`, for example, Entity Framework will have to a join with `AspNetUsers`, and joins are always less efficient that just querying a single-table. However, this method does allow you set enforce NOT NULL on subtype properties at a database-level, so it's a trade-off.

**UPDATE**

Identity scaffolds an implementation of `UserManager<TUser>` that is no longer generic. It explicitly specifies `TUser` as `ApplicationUser`, which means any subtype thrown at it will be downcasted to that. What I'm talking about is just changing this class so it remains generic:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager<TUser> : UserManager<TUser>
    where TUser : ApplicationUser
```

Now, you can new up an instance of `ApplicationUserManager<Teacher>` and it will save `Teacher` instances, query only `Teacher` instances, etc. Obviously, if you need to work generally with *all* users, you'll need to new up an instance of `ApplicationUserManager<ApplicationUser>` for that.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to reply Chris. Are there any good examples of single-table inheritance in ASP.NET which I can have a look which are related to my senario?

Comment: Not really sure what you're looking for. It's pretty straight-forward: all the properties from the type and all subtypes go in one table, with an additional `Discriminator` column identifying the exact class that was saved. It's also the default methodology, so if you want to see it in action, just inherit one entity from another and take a look at what happens at the DB level.

Comment: Ok so im slowly getting my head round Identity 2.0 however I am still a little confused. So with the current set-up I have when I create a new Teacher object when the user clicks on the register button a new record will be added to the AspNetUsers table with the Discriminator column containing Teacher to show that this user is an instance of a Teacher object? Am i right?

Comment: Yep. That's it exactly. Everything is still a user as far as Identity is concerned, but in scenarios where you need a `Teacher` explicitly, you can get that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ChrisPratt. Also, I have a foriegn key in my **Subjects** table to the **TeacherID** as each subject will have a Teacher assosiated with it. Since there is no Teachers table anymore How would I add the foriegn key to the subjects table from the AspNetUsers table?.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Discriminator column says **ApplicationUser** even when a new **Teacher** is registered. Is this normal as the teacher inherits from the ApplicationUser class or should it say Teacher?

Comment: It should say teacher. The problem is with `UserManager`. It's typed to a particular user class. So your default implementation, `ApplicationUserManager` utilizes `ApplicationUser`. As a result, anything like `Teacher` is going to be downcast to `ApplicationUser` when you feed it to that. If you want to save a `Teacher`, you need something that implements `UserManager<Teacher>`. The easiest way to do that is to make `ApplicationUserManager` generic as well, so you can feed the specific user-type you need.

Comment: I should mention that you can use your context directly for many actions involving users, and in these cases you can specifically work with `Teacher` for example. This is only an issue with the default implementation of `ApplicationUserManager` provided by the Identity scaffold. Like I said, though, you can always modify that.

Comment: I dont seem to understand what you mean by implementing UserManager<Teacher>. can you please provide examples as I am a total beginer and dont have great knowledge of identity framework

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with Identity specifically, just generics. `UserManager` is generic, but the default implementation Identity scaffolds for you removes the generic by implementing `UserManager<ApplicationUser>`. You just need to modify this class to remain generic. See update above.

Comment: Hello Chris can you have a look at the update i've made above. Im a little confused on how to set up different UserManager's for different types of registrations